# Foundation Orbit Slider: Navigation Arrows referencing to index

Tags: html, slideshow, zurb-foundation

When using Foundation: Orbit Slider, the navigation arrows are not taking me to the next slide but going back to the index page each time.

Markup `

```
<div class="row full-width" id="portfolio">
        <div class="orbit-container">
          <ul data-orbit class="example-orbit orbit-slides-container">
            <li>
              <img src="/Users/benhare/Desktop/foundation/portfolio/assets/slider2.jpg" alt="slide 1" />
              <div class="orbit-caption">
                Caption One.
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="active">
              <img src="/Users/benhare/Desktop/foundation/portfolio/assets/slider2.jpg" />
              <div class="orbit-caption">
                Caption Two.
              </div>
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="/Users/benhare/Desktop/foundation/portfolio/assets/slider3.jpg" alt="slide 3" />
              <div class="orbit-caption">
                Caption Three.
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
          <a href="#" class="orbit-prev">Prev <span></span></a>
          <a href="#" class="orbit-next">Next <span></span></a>

          <!-- Slide Numbers -->
          <div class="orbit-slide-number">
            <span>1</span> of <span>3</span>
          </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Remove the following classes and rows (they are added by the JS automatically):

- `example-orbit`
- `orbit-slides-container`
- `active`
- everything after the `<\ul>`

Add closing tag to the `<div class="orbit-container">`

So your code will be this:

```
<div class="row full-width" id="portfolio">
    <div class="orbit-container">
      <ul data-orbit="">
        <li>
          <img src="/Users/benhare/Desktop/foundation/portfolio/assets/slider2.jpg" alt="slide 1" />
          <div class="orbit-caption">
            Caption One.
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <img src="/Users/benhare/Desktop/foundation/portfolio/assets/slider2.jpg" />
          <div class="orbit-caption">
            Caption Two.
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <img src="/Users/benhare/Desktop/foundation/portfolio/assets/slider3.jpg"   alt="slide 3" />
          <div class="orbit-caption">
            Caption Three.
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It can be also a good idea to put the `<div class="orbit-container">` into an additional div with `class="large-12 columns"`, and to use a different image inside the first and second slide. I have no other ideas. It also took me a while to figure out how Orbit correctly works.